# Flutter: Ad failed to load : 1

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, rewardedvideoad, google-mobile-ads

I am using the google_mobile_ads package. And it is showing me this error. I am trying to user rewarded video test ads. And they are not loading.

```
Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("7D77F0F7912B63850A1FB8986F58DE38") to get test ads on this device.
 Not retrying to fetch app settings
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the device you are using to the list of test devices to get test ads on it:

```
await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
```

Add this after initialization:

```
MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(
    RequestConfiguration(
        tagForChildDirectedTreatment: 
      TagForChildDirectedTreatment.unspecified,
        testDeviceIds: <String>[
          "7D77F0F7912B63850A1FB8986F58DE38",
        ],
   ),
);
```

Comment: how to get deviceId?

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines:

```
List<String> testDeviceIds = ['YOUR DEVICE ID'];
  RequestConfiguration configuration = RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: testDeviceIds);
  await MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

make sure to use `await` since its an async function

**Getting the device id:**

Simply run your app and request the rewarded ad. You will get some errors in the log, search for this line. The highlighted part is your device id you can add: `RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("**289234E6**")`